# Is it possible to connect to router's admin interface when the router is currently in switch mode?

Tags: networking, router

I have a main `router+modem` which connects me to internet and since I needed more than 4 ports I have used another router (with ddwrt) as a switch (by that I mean I connected LAN port of `main_router` to LAN port of `switch_router`). This setup works fine.

My network scheme (simplified) :

```
                             |--> PC1            |-> PC3
ISP -> `main_router(+modem)`-|--> switch_router -|-> myPC
                             |--> PC2            |-> PC4
```

As you already guessed all `PC`'s are in `main_router`'s network and I can access admin interface of `main_router` directly via its IP.

So far I know that I can disconnect `switch_router` from `main_router`, restart it and then I can connect to admin interface (my pc is already connected to `switch_router`) but this is time consuming and I am lazy to walk to the router.

My question is - can I connect to the admin interface of `switch_router` from `myPC` directly (either to the web interface or via ssh)?

EDIT(clarifications):  `main_router` has DHCP ON. I didn't configure anything on `switch_router` so it is quite possible that DHCP is ON there because of firmware defaults. Routers don't have the same IP as far as I can tell, at least, I can always connect to  `main_router` by its IP.

Comment: it worked will all routers i had - so i would say yes. You might need to configure `switch_router` to use static IP address first ( if you use DHCP, you won't know where to connect otherwise).

Comment: From your description it sounds like both routers have DHCP active (which is bad) and they both have the same IP address (also bad). Mind adding more details on that?

Comment: @MarekRost Could you please describe what you did?

Comment: @grawity Edited the question to add details you have asked.

Comment: When you were connecting to the 2nd router's control panel, what IP address did you use _then_?

Comment: @user1264176  depends on OS on the router - my exact guide won't be much help to you. This didn't work for you ? https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Switch   . Key part to configure before putting `switch_router` into the network is the IP address - it NEEDS to be on same subnet as `main_router` but outside of DHCP range defined on `main_router` - so something like 192.168.0.2 if your subnet is 192.168.0.0/24.

Comment: @grawity When I unplug `switch_router` from `main` and reboot the router I would get default address for it (192.168.1.1) while my `main` operates in 192.168.5.x range. When `switch` is plugged, `myPC` (thru it) is in 192.168.5.x network. I suppose when `switch` is unplugged from `main` it 'becomes' a router.

Comment: No, it's always a router; your computer just doesn't use it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention in the comments that the two routers are configured for different subnets (on their LAN interfaces), and that both have DHCP servers active despite being on the same broadcast domain. The latter, and especially the combination of both, can cause quite a few weird issues, so you should fix that along the way.

- First, since switch_router's IP address is on a different subnet, the *easiest* temporary way to connect to it would be to reconfigure your computer for that subnet.

  That is, manually set the PC's IP address to e.g. `192.168.1.42` (with prefix length `/24` aka netmask `255.255.255.0`). Now you'll be able to reach the switch_router at `192.168.1.1`.
- Once you get that working, **turn off the DHCP service** on switch_router. When you have multiple DHCP servers on the same broadcast domain, by default they'll both respond to configuration requests and your computers just pick the one answer that arrives faster. (If you're lucky, that's the main router... most of the time.)

  So in your current setup there's always a risk of some computer choosing "switch_router" as its default gateway and losing Internet connection. (Since that router also advertises a different subnet, the PC would lose *LAN* connection too.)
- At the same time, change switch_router's LAN IP address to something within the main LAN subnet, e.g. `192.168.5.2`. The address should be outside main_router's DHCP pool range to avoid conflicts. Don't use the same address for both routers!
- Now you can reconfigure the PC back to "automatic" (DHCP) address assignment, and it should be able to reach both <del>routers</del> <del>switches</del> devices using their `192.168.5.*` addresses.

Comment: Thanks, I have configured it per your instructions and it works fine. 
For those who spent some time wondering why you change LAN address but the setup doesn't work - check if you router requires reboot for it. Mine required and it took me 10 minutes to figure out why I cannot connect.